# CSS links background color width

Tags: css

How can you set a link inside of a li element to where its background is longer that the actual text and they are all even with one another?

[image: Example]

**CSS**

```
.popoutsidebar li { margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 5px; }
.popoutsidebar li a { background-color: #E5E5E5; color: #B94A48; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; }
.popoutsidebar li a:hover { background-color: #B94A48; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: can we see a jsfiddle or some html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a>`nchor tags are inline by default. Try something like this:

```
.popoutsidebar li a { display:block }
```

The `display` property lets you define how a certain HTML element should be displayed.

> **display: block** means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace
> above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except
> when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another
> element, for instance).
>
> **display: inline** means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks
> does the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the
> smallest possible width.
>
> http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Comment: That fixes it! Haha Thanks. So by switching it to a block it fills the row.

Comment: Correct. I added an explanation of the differences between the two display types to my answer.